# Inno Setup SignTool Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android

I am trying to add a sign tool to my app installation setup.

I have opened the installation script in Inno setup, then use **Tools to Configure Sign Tools...** Named it **MsSign** and used the path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin<sdk version>\x64\SignTool.exe** for the sign tool.
I added SignTool=MsSign $f in the .iss file for the installer.
I get an error[Innosetup compile error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOg2k.png)
Here is part of my script

```
[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
SignTool=MsSign $f
AppId={{B6149292-1303-475E-A4E5-F3DA50F61C20}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=D:\Xcreator\Mathsquest\Mathsquest license.Tops.txt
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=D:\Xcreator\Mathsquest\Mathsquest Installer Modise
OutputBaseFilename=MATHSQuestSetup
SetupIconFile=D:\Xcreator\Mathsquest\icon\logo_5_dc0_icon.ico
Password=mq142019tm
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
```

I have installed Windows 10 SDK and Visual studio 2019 community and I get the same error.

How do I fix this. I want to be able to use Inno Setup Extractor to open the app in Android.

Answer (score 0):

SignTool = it's just a string of [whole sign command](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool);

$f = it's for your file name, you need to put it in the end of the sign command (SignTool);

for example MsSign =

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /f "D:\WORK\Projects\YourProject\your.pfx" /fd sha256 /as /p yourpfxpass $f
```